# how to change previous date and current date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql

I have an application where I have to display records between two dates, current date and previous date. 
By default 6 months data are displayed(which is a part of my requirement) but I want to change my previous date during run time(I am passing it from UI) and I don't want to pick future date as current date. 
Below is my code, please help me to solve this, thank you

```
// ------------------- function to change dates --------------------- 
    function changeDates(){        
            var date = new Date();
            var cur_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
            cur_date = cur_date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            cur_date = cur_date.trim();
            var pre_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() - 5, 1);
            pre_date = pre_date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            pre_date = pre_date.trim();
            var xmlhttp;
            xmlhttp.open("GET","dashboard/Ajax/change_date.jsp?pre_date="+pre_date+"&cur_date="+cur_date,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

}

Comment: And wheres your try to implement sth like an input... ?

Comment: call_sts_ps_day_dt2 and 3 are just onblur function as I change date

Comment: so why are they part of the question??

Comment: I included it because it may has to be corrected if it is wrong. You can ignore it if they seem meaningless. The whole objective of the question is if i change dates those changed dates should pass into ajax pages for retrieving queries

Comment: and which problem are you facing??

Comment: once i change date(s), changed date(s) are not passed to ajax page. i.e. only default dates are passed

Comment: and wheres that code?? remove all unneccessary stuff, give proper names to your functions and add your tryings and im may able to help you...

Comment: function changeDates(){

  var date = new Date();

  var cur_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  cur_date = cur_date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
  cur_date = cur_date.trim();
  var pre_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() - 5, 1);
  pre_date = pre_date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
     pre_date = pre_date.trim();

Comment: thats what the *edit* button was made for

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see there are two questions here: 1) Your current date is being created as a future date and 2) You want to be able to override the default pre_date value.

First, when you are calling the Date constructor you are adding a month. This is not necessary. I would read through the MDN on [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```
var cur_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).toString();
```

Second, the function makes no attempt to change the value of pre_date to override the default. Have the function accept the override date

```
function changeDates(previousDate)
```

Then override if a date was passed (you may want to validate the date further):

```
     var pre_date = previousDate ? 
         previousDate : 
         new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() - 5, 1).toString();
```

Also, I would add that the toString() method does not take any arguments and there should be no need to trim the result.